# Generating function of $\binom{3n}{n}$

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, lagrange-inversion

[Wolfram alpha tells me](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5BBinomial%5B3n,n%5Dx%5En,%20%7Bn,%200,%20Infinity%7D%5D) the ordinary generating function of the sequence $\{\binom{3n}{n}\}$ is given by
$$\sum_{n} \binom{3n}{n} x^n = \frac{2\cos[\frac{1}{3}\sin^{-1}(\frac{3\sqrt{3}\sqrt{x}}{2})]}{\sqrt{4-27x}}$$
How do I prove this?

Comment: Note that for $t\approx 0$ we have $\cos(\sin^{-1}(t))=\sqrt{1-t^2}$. This allows you to simplify the right hand side *greatly* and cast doubts on the WA result.

Comment: WA's answers actually has $\cos(\mathbf{1/3}\sin^{-1}(...))$

Comment: Thanks Hagen and Grigory. I made a typo.

Comment: Now more to the point. Using Lagrange inversion formula [one can show](http://mathoverflow.net/a/32261/1556) that if $y^3-y=x$ then $y=-\sum\binom{3n}n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$. Now apply the trigonometric method to the same equation...

Comment: @ColinTan: Since the Lagrange Inversion Formula is useful to answer your question, you could add the tags (lagrange-inversion) and (generating-functions). Regards.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As was already mentioned in the comment section the *Lagrange Inversion Formula* is a proper method to prove this identity. In the following I use the notation from R. Sprugnolis (etal) paper [Lagrange Inversion: when and how](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/226195157_Lagrange_Inversion_When_and_How/file/e0b495230d098ec3f7.pdf).

> Let us suppose that a formal power series $w=w(t)$ is implicitely defined by a relation $w=t\Phi(w)$, where $\Phi(t)$ is a formal power series such that $\Phi(0)\ne0$. The *Lagrange Inversion Formula (LIF)* states that:
>
> $$[t^n]w(t)^k=\frac{k}{n}[t^{n-k}]\Phi(t)^n$$

There are several variations of the LIF stated in the paper. We use in the following $G6$:

> Let $F(t)$ be any formal power series and $w=t\Phi(w)$ as before, then the following is valid:
>
> \begin{align*}
> [t^n]F(t)\Phi(t)^n=\left[\left.\frac{F(w)}{1-t\Phi'(w)}\right|w=t\Phi(w)\right]\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

*Note:* The notation $[\left.f(w)\right|w=g(t)]$ is a linearization of $\left.f(w)\right|_{w=g(t)}$ and denotes the substitution of $g(t)$ to every occurrence of $w$ in $f(w)$ (that is, $f(g(t))$). In particular, $w=t\Phi(w)$ is to be solved in $w=w(t)$ and $w$ has to be substituted in the expression on the left of the $|$ sign.

> We prove the following identity
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n\ge0}\binom{3n}{n}t^n=\frac{2\cos\left[\frac{1}{3}\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{3\sqrt{3}\sqrt{t}}{2}\right)\right]}{\sqrt{4-27t}}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}

$$ $$

> Let $F(t)=1$ and $\Phi(t)=(1+t)^3$.
>
> Since
>   $$t\Phi'(w)=3t(1+w)^2=\frac{3t\Phi(w)}{1+w}=\frac{3w}{1+w}$$
>   we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \binom{3n}{n}&=[t^n]F(t)\Phi(t)^n=[t^n](1+t)^{3n}\\
> &=[t^n]\left[\left.\frac{1}{1-t\Phi'(w)}\right|w=t\Phi(w)\right]=[t^n]\left[\left.\frac{1+w}{1-2w}\right|w=t\Phi(w)\right]\\
> \end{align*}
>   Let
>   \begin{align*}
> A(t):=\sum_{n\ge0}\binom{3n}{n}t^n=\left.\frac{1+w}{1-2w}\right|_{w=t\Phi(w)}
> \end{align*}
>   Expressing $A(t)=\frac{1+w}{1-2w}$ in terms of $w$, we get
>   $$w=\frac{A(t)-1}{2A(t)+1}$$
>   Since $w=t\Phi(w)=t(1+w)^3$, we get
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{A(t)-1}{2A(t)+1}=t\left(1+\frac{A(t)-1}{2A(t)+1}\right)^3
> \end{align*}
>
> which simplifies to:
>
> \begin{align*}
> (4-27t)A(t)^3-3A(t)-1=0\tag{3}
> \end{align*}

In order to get the RHS of $(2)$ we first analyse the structure of $(3)$ which is

$$f(t)A(t)^3-3A(t)=1$$

with $f(t)$ linear and observe a similarity of this structure with the identity

$$4\cos^3{t}-3\cos{t}=\cos{3t}$$

> We use the Ansatz:
>
> $$A(t) := \frac{2\cos\left(g(t)\right)}{\sqrt{4-27t}}$$
>
> and obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> (4-27t)&A(t)^3-3A(t)=\\
> &=\frac{8\cos^3\left(g(t)\right)}{\sqrt{4-27t}}-\frac{6\cos\left(g(t)\right)}{\sqrt{4-27t}}=\\
> &=\frac{2\cos\left(3g(t)\right)}{\sqrt{4-27t}}\\
> &=1
> \end{align*}
>   Since
>   \begin{align*}
> 2\cos\left(3g(t)\right)&=\sqrt{4-27t}\\
> 4\cos^2\left(3g(t)\right)&=4-27t\\
> \sin^2\left(3g(t)\right)&=\frac{27}{4}t\\
> \end{align*}
>   we get
>   \begin{align*}
> g(t)&=\frac{1}{3}\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{3\sqrt{3t}}{2}\right)\\
> &\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\Box
> \end{align*}
>
> and conclude the identity $(2)$ is valid.

Answer (score 3):

**Too long for a comment:** By investigating series of the form $S_a(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty{an\choose n}~x^n$, we notice that — in general — we get a $($ [generalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function) $)$ [hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function) of argument $\dfrac{a^a}{(a-1)^{a-1}}~x$, which then naturally leads us to suspect that we should rather be inspecting the values of the same expression for $x(t)=\dfrac{(a-1)^{a-1}}{a^a}~t$. Taking into consideration the fact that $\displaystyle\lim_{u\to0}u^u=1$, we have

> $$\begin{align}
> S_{-1}\Big(x(t)\Big)~&=~\frac1{\sqrt{1-t}}
> \\\\
> S_{-1/2}\Big(x(t)\Big)~&=~\frac{\cos\bigg(\dfrac{\arcsin t}3\bigg)+\dfrac1{\sqrt3}~\sin\bigg(\dfrac{\arcsin t}3\bigg)}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}
> \\\\
> S_0\Big(x(t)\Big)~&=~0
> \\\\
> S_{1/2}\Big(x(t)\Big)~&=~1-i~\frac{t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}
> \\\\
> S_1\Big(x(t)\Big)~&=~\frac1{1-t}
> \\\\
> S_{3/2}\Big(x(t)\Big)~&=~\frac{\cos\bigg(\dfrac{\arcsin t}3\bigg)+\sqrt3~\sin\bigg(\dfrac{\arcsin t}3\bigg)}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}
> \\\\
> S_2\Big(x(t)\Big)~&=~\frac1{\sqrt{1-t}}
> \\\\
> S_3\Big(x(t)\Big)~&=~\frac{\cos\bigg(\dfrac{\arcsin\sqrt t}3\bigg)}{\sqrt{1-t}}
> \end{align}$$