# Verifying $ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{3k \choose k}\frac{9k^2-3k-1}{(3k-1)(3k-2)}\left(\frac{2}{27}\right)^k=\frac{1}{4}$

Tags: real-analysis, summation

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{3k \choose k}\dfrac{9k^2-3k-1}{(3k-1)(3k-2)}\left(\dfrac{2}{27}\right)^k=\dfrac{1}{4}
$$
After some simplification, I got the following result:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left\{{3k \choose k}+\dfrac{27}{2k}{3k-4 \choose 2k-3}\right\}\left(\dfrac{2}{27}\right)^k.
$$ 
Now, how I can proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Starting with
$$
\eqalign{
  & S = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {
  \binom{3k}{k}{{9k^2  - 3k - 1} \over {\left( {3k - 1} \right)\left( {3k - 2} \right)}}\left( {{2 \over {27}}} \right)^{\,k} }  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {
\binom{3k}{k}  \left( {1 + {1 \over {\left( {3k - 1} \right)}} + {1 \over {\left( {3k - 2} \right)}}} \right)\left( {{2 \over {27}}} \right)^{\,k} }  \cr} 
$$
we have that
$$
\binom{3k}{k} = {{\Gamma \left( {3k + 1} \right)} \over {\Gamma \left( {2k + 1} \right)}}{1 \over {k!}}
$$

Using the $n$-plication formula for the Gamma function
$$
\Gamma \left( {n\,z + 1} \right) = \Gamma \left( {n\,\left( {z + 1/n} \right)} \right)\quad  =
 {{n^{\,n\,z + 1/2} } \over {\left( {2\,\pi } \right)^{\left( {n - 1} \right)/2} }}\prod\limits_{1\, \le \,j\, \le \,n} {\Gamma \left( {z + {j \over n}} \right)} 
$$
we get
$$
\eqalign{
  & {{\Gamma \left( {3\,k + 1} \right)} \over {\Gamma \left( {2\,k + 1} \right)}}\quad
  = {{3^{\,3\,k + 1/2} } \over {2^{\,2\,k + 1/2} \sqrt {2\,\pi } ^\, }}{{\Gamma \left( {k + {1 \over 3}} \right)\Gamma \left( {k + {2 \over 3}} \right)
  \Gamma \left( {k + 1} \right)} \over {\Gamma \left( {k + {1 \over 2}} \right)\Gamma \left( {k + 1} \right)}} =   \cr 
  &  = \sqrt {{3 \over {4\pi }}} {{\Gamma \left( {k + {1 \over 3}} \right)\Gamma \left( {k + {2 \over 3}} \right)}
 \over {\Gamma \left( {k + {1 \over 2}} \right)}}\left( {{27 \over 4}} \right)^{\,k}   \cr 
  & {{\Gamma \left( {3\,k + 1} \right)} \over {\Gamma \left( {2\,k + 1} \right)\left( {3k - 1} \right)}}
 = \sqrt {{3 \over {4\pi }}} {{\Gamma \left( {k + {1 \over 3}} \right)\Gamma \left( {k + {2 \over 3}} \right)}
 \over {3\Gamma \left( {k + {1 \over 2}} \right)\left( {k - 1/3} \right)}}\left( {{27 \over 4}} \right)^{\,k}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sqrt {{3 \over {4\pi }}} {1 \over 3}{{\Gamma \left( {k + {1 \over 3}} \right)\Gamma \left( {k - {1 \over 3}} \right)}
 \over {\Gamma \left( {k + {1 \over 2}} \right)}}\left( {{27 \over 4}} \right)^{\,k}   \cr 
  & {{\Gamma \left( {3\,k + 1} \right)} \over {\Gamma \left( {2\,k + 1} \right)\left( {3k - 2} \right)}}
 = \sqrt {{3 \over {4\pi }}} {{\Gamma \left( {k + {1 \over 3}} \right)\Gamma \left( {k + {2 \over 3}} \right)}
 \over {3\Gamma \left( {k + {1 \over 2}} \right)\left( {k - 2/3} \right)}}\left( {{27 \over 4}} \right)^{\,k}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sqrt {{3 \over {4\pi }}} {1 \over 3}{{\Gamma \left( {k - {2 \over 3}} \right)\Gamma \left( {k + {2 \over 3}} \right)}
 \over {\Gamma \left( {k + {1 \over 2}} \right)}}\left( {{27 \over 4}} \right)^{\,k}  \cr} 
$$

So
$$
\eqalign{
  & S =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\binom{3k}{k}
  \left( {1 + {1 \over {\left( {3k - 1} \right)}} + {1 \over {\left( {3k - 2} \right)}}} \right)\left( {{2 \over {27}}} \right)^{\,k} }  =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over 2}\sqrt {{1 \over {3\pi }}} \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {
 \left( {3{{\Gamma \left( {k + {1 \over 3}} \right)\Gamma \left( {k + {2 \over 3}} \right)} \over {\Gamma \left( {k + {1 \over 2}} \right)}}
 + {{\Gamma \left( {k + {1 \over 3}} \right)\Gamma \left( {k - {1 \over 3}} \right)} \over {\Gamma \left( {k + {1 \over 2}} \right)}}
 + {{\Gamma \left( {k - {2 \over 3}} \right)\Gamma \left( {k + {2 \over 3}} \right)}
 \over {\Gamma \left( {k + {1 \over 2}} \right)}}} \right){{\left( {1/2} \right)^{\,k} } \over {k!}}}  \cr} 
$$

Using the Hypergeometric function that becomes
$$
\eqalign{
  & S =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over 2}\sqrt {{1 \over {3\pi }}} \left( \matrix{
  3{{\Gamma \left( {1/3} \right)\Gamma \left( {2/3} \right)} \over {\Gamma \left( {1/2} \right)}}{}_2F_1 \left( {\left. {\matrix{
   {1/3,\;2/3}  \cr    {1/2}  \cr 
 } \,} \right|\;{1 \over 2}} \right) +  \hfill \cr 
   + {{\Gamma \left( {1/3} \right)\Gamma \left( { - 1/3} \right)} \over {\Gamma \left( {1/2} \right)}}{}_2F_1 \left( {\left. {\matrix{
   {1/3,\; - 1/3}  \cr    {1/2}  \cr 
 } \,} \right|\;{1 \over 2}} \right) +  \hfill \cr 
   + {{\Gamma \left( {2/3} \right)\Gamma \left( { - 2/3} \right)} \over {\Gamma \left( {1/2} \right)}}{}_2F_1 \left( {\left. {\matrix{
   {2/3,\; - 2/3}  \cr    {1/2}  \cr 
 } \,} \right|\;{1 \over 2}} \right) \hfill \cr}  \right) =   \cr 
  &  = {}_2F_1 \left( {\left. {\matrix{   {1/3,\;2/3}  \cr    {1/2}  \cr  } \,} \right|\;{1 \over 2}} \right)
 - {}_2F_1 \left( {\left. {\matrix{   {1/3,\; - 1/3}  \cr    {1/2}  \cr  } \,} \right|\;{1 \over 2}} \right)
 - {1 \over 2}{}_2F_1 \left( {\left. {\matrix{   {2/3,\; - 2/3}  \cr    {1/2}  \cr  } \,} \right|\;{1 \over 2}} \right) \cr} 
$$

Since the hypergeometric for the variable $z=1/2$
follows the following formulas (see e.g. [this link](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/03/04/ShowAll.html)) 
$$
\eqalign{
  & {}_2F_1 \left( {\left. {\matrix{   {a,\;b}  \cr    {{{a + b} \over 2}}  \cr  } \,} \right|\;{1 \over 2}} \right)
 = \sqrt \pi  \;\Gamma \left( {{{a + b} \over 2}} \right)\left( {{1 \over {\Gamma \left( {{{a + 1} \over 2}} \right)\Gamma \left( {{b \over 2}} \right)}}
 + {1 \over {\Gamma \left( {{a \over 2}} \right)\Gamma \left( {{{b + 1} \over 2}} \right)}}} \right)  \cr 
  & {}_2F_1 \left( {\left. {\matrix{   {a,\;b}  \cr    {{{a + b + 1} \over 2}}  \cr  } \,} \right|\;{1 \over 2}} \right)
 = \sqrt \pi  \;\Gamma \left( {{{a + b + 1} \over 2}} \right){1 \over {\Gamma \left( {{{a + 1} \over 2}} \right)\Gamma \left( {{{b + 1} \over 2}} \right)}} \cr} 
$$
then
$$
\eqalign{
  & {}_2F_1 \left( {\left. {\matrix{   {1/3,\;2/3}  \cr    {1/2}  \cr } \,} \right|\;{1 \over 2}} \right)
  = \pi \left( {{1 \over {\Gamma \left( {2/3} \right)\Gamma \left( {1/3} \right)}}
 + {1 \over {\Gamma \left( {1/6} \right)\Gamma \left( {1 - 1/6} \right)}}} \right) =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {{3 \over {2\sqrt 3 }} + {1 \over 2}} \right) = {{\sqrt 3  + 1} \over 2}  \cr 
  & {}_2F_1 \left( {\left. {\matrix{   {1/3,\; - 1/3}  \cr    {1/2}  \cr  } \,} \right|\;{1 \over 2}} \right)
 = \pi {1 \over {\Gamma \left( {2/3} \right)\Gamma \left( {1/3} \right)}} = {{\sqrt 3 } \over 2}  \cr 
  & {}_2F_1 \left( {\left. {\matrix{   {2/3,\; - 2/3}  \cr    {1/2}  \cr  } \,} \right|\;{1 \over 2}} \right)
 = \pi {1 \over {\Gamma \left( {1 - {1 \over 6}} \right)\Gamma \left( {{1 \over 6}} \right)}} = {1 \over 2} \cr} 
$$

And $S= 1/4$ follows.

Answer (score 0):

By Lagrange's inversion theorem (see [Bring radical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_radical) for the quintic analogue)
$$ \sum_{k\geq 0}\binom{3k}{k}\left(\frac{4}{27}\right)^k x^{2k} = \frac{\cos\left(\frac{1}{3}\arcsin x\right)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}  \tag{1}$$
and by partial fraction decomposition
$$ \frac{9k^2-3k-1}{(3k-1)(3k-2)} = 1+\frac{1}{3k-1}+\frac{1}{3k-2}\tag{2} $$
hence by evaluating $(1)$ at $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ we immediately get
$$ \sum_{k\geq 0}\binom{3k}{k}\left(\frac{2}{27}\right)^k = \frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2}.  \tag{3}$$
By reindexing the original series equals
$$-\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{k\geq 0}\binom{3k}{k}\frac{3(3k+2)(3k+1)}{(2k+2)(2k+1)}\left[1+\frac{1}{3k+1}+\frac{1}{3k+2}\right]\left(\frac{2}{27}\right)^k \tag{4}$$
hence it is enough to compute the integrals over $(0,1/\sqrt{2})$ of the RHS of $(1)$ and of the RHS of $(1)$ multiplied by $x$. They are $\frac{3}{2\sqrt{2}}(\sqrt{3}-1)$ and $\frac{3}{16}(5-2\sqrt{3})$ by the substitution $x\mapsto\sin\theta$. By re-combining these pieces the claim is proved.

Comment: @J.Doe: An application of the Lagrange inversion theorem to 
 calculate $\sum_{k}\binom{3k}{k}x^k$ can   be found for instance at *[this  post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/774434/generating-function-of-binom3nn/815207#815207)*.