# Evaluate: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {\left(\frac{-100}{729}\right)}^n {3n \choose n}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, summation, taylor-expansion

The questions asks to evaluate: 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {\left(\frac{-100}{729}\right)}^n {3n \choose n}$$
The answer provided is $-\frac{1}{4}$, but I don't know how to solve it.  I am not sure how to approach this series.

Comment: Anything you tried?

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3270761).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A generating function of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {3n \choose n}z^n$ can be derived using *[Lagrange Inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem)* and is given as
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {3n \choose n}z^n=\frac{2\cos\left(\frac{1}{3}\arcsin\left(\frac{3\sqrt{3}\sqrt{z}}{2}\right)\right)}{\sqrt{4-27z}}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

which is shown in *[this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/774434/generating-function-of-binom3nn/815207#815207)*.

> Here we need (1) evaluated at $z=-\frac{100}{729}$. We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}}\color{blue}{ {3n \choose n}\left(-\frac{100}{729}\right)^n}
> &=\left.\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{27}{4}z}}\cos\left(\frac{1}{3}\arcsin\left(\sqrt{\frac{27}{4}z}\right)\right)\right|_{z=-\frac{100}{729}}-1\\
> &=\frac{3\sqrt{39}}{26}\cos\left(\frac{1}{3}\arcsin\left(\frac{5}{3\sqrt{3}}i\right)\right)-1\tag{2}\\
> &=\frac{3\sqrt{39}}{26}\cos\left(-\frac{i}{3}\ln\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{25}{27}}-\frac{5}{3\sqrt{3}}\right)\right)-1\tag{3}\\
> &=\frac{3\sqrt{39}}{26}\cos\left(-\frac{i}{3}\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{52}-5}{3\sqrt{3}}\right)\right)-1\\
> &=\frac{3\sqrt{39}}{52}\left(\left(\frac{\sqrt{52}-5}{3\sqrt{3}}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}+\left(\frac{\sqrt{52}-5}{3\sqrt{3}}\right)^{-\frac{1}{3}}\right)-1\tag{4}\\
> &=\frac{3\sqrt{39}}{52}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\left(\sqrt{52}-5\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\left(\sqrt{52}-5\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}\right)-1\tag{5}\\
> &=\frac{3\sqrt{13}}{52}\left(\left(\sqrt{52}-5\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}+\left(\sqrt{52}+5\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}\right)-1\tag{6}\\
> &=\frac{3}{4}\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{13}}\left(\left(2\sqrt{13}-5\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}+\left(2\sqrt{13}+5\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}\right)-1\\
> &=\frac{3}{4}\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{13}}\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{13}-1\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{13}+1\right)\right)-1\tag{7}\\
> &=\frac{3}{4}\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{13}}\sqrt{13}-1\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=-\frac{1}{4}}
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (2)     we evaluate the function at $z=-\frac{100}{729}$.
- In (3)     we use the *[identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Logarithmic_forms)*
  $\arcsin(z)=-i\ln\left(\sqrt{1-z^2}+iz\right),\quad z\ne-1,1$.
- In (4)     we use $\cos(z)=\frac{1}{2}\left(e^{iz}+e^{-iz}\right)$.
- In (5) we factor out $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$.
- In (6) we cancel $\sqrt{3}$.
- In (7)     we use the identity $2\sqrt{13}\pm5=\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{13}\pm1\right)\right)^3$.